# PHP get a value from array index

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have this string:

```
$hours = '7, 8, 12';
$hourData = explode(', ', $hours);
```

if I `var_dump($hourData)`, it returns:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "7"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "8"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "12"
}
```

and I have this code:

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i <= 23 ; $i++) { ?>
    <div class="fl">
        <input type="checkbox" name="limit_hour[]" value="<?php echo $i ?>" class="fl limit_hour"
        <!-- ======================================================================== -->
        <?php echo (isset($hourData[$i]) && $i == $hourData[$i] ? 'checked' : '') ?>>
        <!-- ======================================================================== -->
        <span class="fl lmBox"><?php echo $i ?>:00 - <?php echo $i ?>:59</span>
    </div>  
<?php } ?>
```

this code:

```
<?php echo (isset($hourData[$i]) && $i == $hourData[$i] ? 'checked' : '') ?>
```

I want to ***echo***  **'checked'** for the checkbox who got the same value as my **$hourData** array value.

What should I do?

Comment: I asume $i is the hour.
'in_array($i, $hourData)' would return a true/false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just follow up the ternary and use `in_array()`

```
<?php echo (in_array($i, $hourData) ? 'checked' : ''); ?>
```

Much like this:

```
<input 
    type="checkbox" 
    name="limit_hour[]" 
    value="<?php echo $i; ?>" 
    class="fl limit_hour"
    <?php echo (in_array($i, $hourData) ? 'checked' : ''); ?> 
/>
```

Using `$hourData[$i]` wouldn't make sense since they will never match.

First Iteration:

```
$i = 0
(isset($hourData[$i]) && $i == $hourData[$i]
   ^ $hourData[$i]   AND  0 == $hourData[$i] // 7
      this does exist
```

Comment: yes this solved my problem :D, I never thought it would be this simple, thank you sir :D

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you actually want the value not index. I.e. check if $i exists as value in $hourData array.

```
<?php
echo in_array($i, $hourData) ? 'checked' : ''
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i <= 23 ; $i++) { 
 if(in_array($i, $hourData){
     $checked = "checked";
 }else{
     $checked = "";
 }
?>
    <div class="fl">
        <input type="checkbox" name="limit_hour[]" value="<?php echo $i ?>" class="fl limit_hour" <?php echo $checked; ?>>
        <!-- ======================================================================== -->
        <span class="fl lmBox"><?php echo $i ?>:00 - <?php echo $i ?>:59</span>
    </div>  
<?php } ?>
```

this will set the checked value if there is else it leaves it empty, so it works fine.

As I stated in a comment: "I asume $i is the hour. 'in_array($i, $hourData)' would return a true/false."

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that comparing if a value is contained in an array is sufficient:

```
 <?php echo (in_array($i, $hourData)) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''); ?>
```